# Gradle failed to find library

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Am using android studio. Have the following dependencies. Gradle fails to find the third party libraries volley and square but DOES find appcompat:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+@aar'
compile 'com.squareup.phrase:phrase:1.0.3'
```

.

```
Error:Failed to find: com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+
```

I have updated Android SDK Manager tools and Extras including support library but still no luck. I have tried both with jcenter() and mavenCentral(). Can anyone help ?

`build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies{

    }
}
```

`app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tap"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.phrase:phrase:1.0.3'
}
```

`settings.gradle`:

```
include ':app'
```

Comment: use this in dependencies compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+' for more details refer https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your volley dependency (in build.gradle of your project app structure level) from

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+@aar'
```

to

```
 compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
```

& include mavenCentral() in repositories section.
    In your app/build.gradle, add mavenCentral() in repositories section after release section.

> Note - Google doesn’t provide a build of Volley for Gradle but there are mirrored copies of Volley published for use in Gradle.

See [Unofficial mirror for android-volley library here](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley).

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

And change you dependencies section to look alike:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
compile 'com.squareup.phrase:phrase:1.0.3'
```

}

Comment: Hi similar response i gave to Sohil, i have tried the different compile paths with mavenCentral() and jcenter(). I have tried the above as you have suggested just to be sure. Outcome is the same, i get the same error.

Comment: How about adding external jars as dependencies as suggested by @Sohil, is your gradle failing again to find these dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

1.Remove all dependencies like this.

```
dependencies {

}
```

2. Rebuilt
3. Again add all dependencies like this

   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
       compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'

   }
4. Sync

Hope its work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace Volley Library dependencies with below one:

```
'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.1'
```

Comment: Hi, i think the issue is not the path as i have tried this one already, also i get the same issue with any dependency i put in other than appcompat

Comment: @DeveloperDH - The other option is that you can download the '.jars' externally from here and put it under lib folder. **Volley.jar - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mcxiaoke.volley/library-aar/1.0.1 and Squareup.jar - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.phrase/phrase/1.0.3 **

Once you have downloaded copy that jar under `Project Folder > app (your module folder) > libs (if not exists then create) > copy files here.`

Comment: hi, yes that is the work around i have been using but am trying to resolve this for the long term. Thanks for getting back to me, I am surprised no one on stackoverflow has come forward with a solution,

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade of android studio to 1.3.2 resolved the issue, unfortunately i do not know what version i had previously.